# Detect Battery Insertion in USB Charging Circuit

Tags: usb, battery-charging, lithium-ion, zener, current-sensing

I'm using an MCP73831T as the charger IC, I've figured out how to detect the charging/charged, this was easy, however, I would like to know when the battery is actually plugged in, I know when the usb power is in via the PWR_SENSE, this works good, so I can deduce that if the usb is not plugged in and the MCU is running then obviously the battery is connected, the problem is detecting whether the battery is plugged in while the usb is also plugged in.

I've tried a couple sensing circuits, the "SECOND TRY" (see schematic below) might work, I can read an ADC value and if it is essentially higher or lower than ~N (where ~N is just about some number, e.g. 900ish), when the battery is charging the value will be < ~900 and when the battery is charged it will be > ~1000, though I feel like there is a better way this can be done.

This is all very new to me still so I'm at a wall at the moment on other options and search hasn't helped. I know that the battery voltage will be no more than 4.2v, which is why I was thinking somehow using a zener, e.g. the VUSB will be > 4.2V, the battery will be <= 4.2v, I feel like I can use this, but not sure how.

Anyhow, here is the schematic I have, the green lines is the normal charging circuit, which seems to all work well, the blue is one try with an ACS712 and the orange is another try.

Any ideas? am I on the right track?

[image]

Comment: You just need to use a somewhat more sophisticated charger IC, not this primitive one. Take a look, for example, at Texas instruments portfolio of Power Management ICs BQxxxxx series, or something. These ICs will sense everything, and manage everything.